# Why does Ruby keep thinking my class is actually a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

might be a really dumb question here but I've been scratching my head trying to figure out why ruby is doing this.

Basically I have a file in app/lib I am trying to reference in another file(User.rb) within app/models

```
module A
  module B
    class C
      attr_reader :example_var
      def initialize(example_var)
        @example_var = example_var
      end

      def self.example()
        return "something"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However when trying to reference this in app/models/User.rb like so:
`::A::B::C.example()`

Ruby shows this error:
`undefined method 'example' for A::B::C:Module`
Which is weird right? Shouldn't it at least show
`undefined method 'example' for A::B::C:Class`

I've checked the config within application.rb and the path looks fine.
`config.autoload_paths += %W( #{Rails.root}/lib )`

Also there are other files that have this same format in different folders that are getting referenced perfectly fine. Which is why I am really stuck on why this error is showing up.

Comment: There is probably some important detail you aren't showing us.  I'd search for all instances of the string `C` and see if there is a module defined somewhere with that name.  I'd print out `A::B::C.class` and `Object.const_source_location('A::B::C')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am dumb. I figured it out, posting in case others make a similar mistake.

I messed up creating the file in the directory structure. It was structured like so.

```
A
 ->B
    ->C
       ->C.rb
```

So in the first few lines, Ruby expected

```
module A
  module B
    module C
       class C
```

but I was providing

```
module A
  module B
    class C
```

Comment: Rails might have expected this Ruby has no expectations regarding directory structure. Additionally if that was the true issue I would have expected an uninitialized constant error, rather than what you are showing which based on the post this description is Rails magically created a `module C` out of thin air.

Comment: @engineersmnky this isn't really Rails - its Zeitwerk and a feature called auto-vivification or implicit namespaces. Given the file `foo/bar/baz.rb` Zeitwerk will automatically create the modules Foo and Bar unless they already exist. https://www.urbanautomaton.com/blog/2020/11/04/rails-autoloading-heaven/#implicit-namespaces

Comment: @max ruby libraries and rails especially just continue to get more horrifying. It's almost as if the dynamic nature of ruby is so enchanting that people are innately drawn (and fundamentally encouraged) to turn degenerate POC projects into fully functional libraries. To clarify by "horrifying" I mean beautiful esoteric chaos that borders on the mystic.

Comment: @engineersmnky Zeitwerk has some pretty crazy ideas but at least it works a lot more reliably then the classic autoloader.

Comment: @max wait till `did_you_mean` starts autocorrecting at Runtime. 

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure why it throws error to you .

```
[3] pry(main)> module A
[3] pry(main)*   module B
[3] pry(main)*     class C
[3] pry(main)*       attr_reader :example_var
[3] pry(main)*       def initialize(example_var)
[3] pry(main)*         @example_var = example_var
[3] pry(main)*       end
[3] pry(main)*
[3] pry(main)*       def self.example()
[3] pry(main)*         return "something"
[3] pry(main)*       end
[3] pry(main)*     end
[3] pry(main)*   end
[3] pry(main)* end
=> :example
[4] pry(main)> A::B::C.example()
=> "something"
[5] pry(main)> ::A::B::C.example()
=> "something"
[6] pry(main)>
```

You can understand more concepts in this [blog](https://blog.polleverywhere.com/sharing-code-ruby-rails/).